# Set the logo for an Azure Application using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API it is possible to create Azure Applications using the applications end point. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

An application has a logo and when you add it through the Azure Portal then the info/logoUrl property has a value. How do you set the logo through the graph? I've tried setting it to a url and there is no error, but the value does not get set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in another reply, the `info/logoUrl` is `Read-only` in Microsoft Graph, we could not set it directly, also per my test, even the request returns `204`, it will not take effect.

My workaround is to use the [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog), you could try the request below in the postman, it works on my side.

Request URL:

```
PUT https://graph.windows.net/<tenant-id>/applications/<object-id>/mainLogo?api-version=1.6
```

In the postman,  `Authorization` -> `Bearer token` -> fill your token, in the `Body`, select `binary` -> `Select file`, then `Send`.

**Note**: Your picture could not be large, otherwise you will get a `The stream write request would result in an excessive number of bytes being written` error.

[image]

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

---

**Besides**, if you just want to set the logo Programmatically, you could use the powershell [`Set-AzureADApplicationLogo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplicationlogo?view=azureadps-2.0), it is the easiest way I can find.

```
Set-AzureADApplicationLogo -ObjectId <object-id> -FilePath C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\pic1.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm now using the Azure Graph to set the logo successfully.

Comment: I've discovered a seemingly new endpoint within the newer Microsoft Graph API v1.0 which I've written about in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Graph API v1.0 now supports uploading logos, although I was unable to find this particular endpoint in their documentation but this may be because the v1.0 API is only a couple of weeks old at time of writing.

Request:

```
Content-Type: image/png
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<object-id>/logo
<binary content>
```

In Postman, you can set binary body content by going to Body and then clicking binary from the radio buttons. Make sure you set the Content-Type header accordingly, e.g. image/png for a .png file

[image: Postman binary content]

You will receive a `204 No Content` empty response on success, it appears to take effect immediately in the Azure Portal when viewing the App Registration.

Comment: As an aside, I've raised a GitHub issue on their documentation to add this endpoint: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7854

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we can't modify the logo through the Microsoft Graph API.

The `info/logoUrl` is read-only based on [informationalUrl resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/informationalurl?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).