# Set the logo for an Azure Application using Microsoft Graph PATCH call with request body as image URL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Here we can update logo by this url  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/application-id/logo.

But I want update the logo using Microsoft Patch API while creating the application using Microsoft graph api. Because Users need to pass image url sometimes . I found this document   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorial-applications-basics?tabs=http . Here we can update the logo by using image URL. Also I read in place logoUrl we need to pass CDN image links only.

JSON payload is

```
{
    "info": {
        "logoUrl": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/21/23/25/link-1271843_1280.png",
        "marketingUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/app/marketing",
        "privacyStatementUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/app/privacy",
        "supportUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/app/support",
        "termsOfServiceUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/app/termsofservice"
    }
}
```

It is given 204 content status All other fields are updated . But logo not uploaded in azure application.

Comment: Updating logo only works with PUT method. Can you try changing PATCH method to PUT and run the query again?

Comment: This endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/application-Id/.  is Patch call.  If I make it is Put. It was showing 405 method not allowed

Answer (score 0):

> According to this [MS  Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20PUT%20method%20to%20update%20the%20logo.), you need to use **PUT query** to update the logo. You cannot update it with `info/logoUrl` as it is **read-only** based on [informationalUrl resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/informationalurl?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

I have registered one Azure AD application named **`GraphApp`** with below properties:

[image]

To update above properties, I ran below `PATCH` request and got **response** like this:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<appObjectID>/

{
    "info": {
        "logoUrl": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/21/23/25/link-1271843_1280.png",
        "marketingUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/app/marketing",
        "privacyStatementUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/app/privacy",
        "supportUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/app/support",
        "termsOfServiceUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/app/termsofservice"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, all properties updated **except logo** like this:

[image]

To update logo, you need to use `PUT` method by adding image in binary **stream** along with `Content-Type` header like below:

```http
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<appObjectID>/logo
Authorization:Bearer <access_token>
Content-Type:image/png
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **logo** uploaded successfully to the application like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Set the logo for an Azure Application using Microsoft Graph - Stack Overflow by **MattJeanes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099806/set-the-logo-for-an-azure-application-using-microsoft-graph)